# Запуск нескольких экземпляров программы (например, калькулятора)

Tags: c#, процесс

Как создать несколько процессов одной программы, будь то блокнот или калькулятор?

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "calc.exe";
p.Start();
```

Так получаем 1 вызванный процесс, и вторым способом:

```
Process.Start("c://Windows//System32//calc.exe");
```

Втором пытался делать через цикл, но не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос на самом деле не так уж и тривиален.

Для того, чтобы запустить *один* экземпляр калькулятора, достаточно простого

```
Process.Start("calc.exe");
```

(поскольку `calc.exe` находится в [списке известных программ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx#appPaths)).

Для того, чтобы запустить его в нескольких экземплярах, по идее должно быть достаточно простого

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    Process.Start("calc.exe");
```

Но этот код в моём случае всё равно открывает лишь одно окно калькулятора. Судя по всему, процесс калькулятора проверяет, что он запущен несколько раз подряд с мизерным временным интервалом, предполагает, что пользователь просто случайно нажал на иконку лишний раз, и не запускает последующие экземпляры.

Поэтому пришлось добавить небольшой интервал:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    if (i > 0)
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    Process.Start("calc.exe");
}
```

Такой код на моей системе (Windows 10) открывает три экземпляра калькулятора без проблем.